# Please help me interpret this goodness of fit test

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

In the game of Bridge, 52 cards are distrubuted randomly among 4 players, each player ending up with 13 cards.

I implemented a random number generator using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider form the Microsoft .Net Framerowk to first draw a number from the range 1-52, then from the range 1-51 and so on up to the range 1-2.
To see if at a given range of 1 to x, where 2>= x <=52, any number in this range is equally likely to be selected I implemented the following test:

- Draw 52* 10 million times from a range of 1-52 and keep track of how often a number from this range comes up. Apply a goodness of fit test against an expected frequency of 10 million for each number.

  - Draw 51* 10 million times from a range of 1-51 and keep track of how often a number from this range comes up. Apply a goodness of fit test against an expected frequency of 10 million for each number.

And so forth until we reach the range 1-2.

Below you find the p values for each number of cards, when it is lower than 0.05 the observered number of draws for each number in the range is printed.

In the sample below for two ranges the p value indeed was lower than 0.05.

Should I now conclude that the RNGCryptoServiceProvider is not capable of producing an equal distrbution for all ranges in the range 1-52, 1-51, ... 1-2?

Test Name:  CardChances
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:
Debug Trace:

P value for 52 cards=0.79474227840984

P value for 51 cards=0.497191145912234

P value for 50 cards=0.391892735550181

P value for 49 cards=0.988683559265785

P value for 48 cards=0.153114936344037

P value for 47 cards=0.927327644547415

P value for 46 cards=0.493708839113774

P value for 45 cards=0.35952495612322

P value for 44 cards=0.979430525949886

P value for 43 cards=0.192281134864909

P value for 42 cards=0.53964228753539

P value for 41 cards=0.175093762735034

P value for 40 cards=0.801225853918414

P value for 39 cards=0.156440626522907

P value for 38 cards=0.186908820122156

P value for 37 cards=0.0828295408060195

P value for 36 cards=0.81408556973856

P value for 35 cards=0.805491467886622

P value for 34 cards=0.336741413336137

P value for 33 cards=0.498471084831715

P value for 32 cards=0.824924933331495

P value for 31 cards=0.163033897868359

P value for 30 cards=0.0967583951496144

P value for 29 cards=0.369476297712753

P value for 28 cards=0.0243850151443583

Card number 1 was drawn 10000359 times.

Card number 2 was drawn 9998315 times.

Card number 3 was drawn 10004012 times.

Card number 4 was drawn 9988701 times.

Card number 5 was drawn 9997630 times.

Card number 6 was drawn 9996076 times.

Card number 7 was drawn 10003135 times.

Card number 8 was drawn 9997429 times.

Card number 9 was drawn 9999151 times.

Card number 10 was drawn 10001832 times.

Card number 11 was drawn 10001967 times.

Card number 12 was drawn 9994442 times.

Card number 13 was drawn 9999789 times.

Card number 14 was drawn 9996959 times.

Card number 15 was drawn 9998547 times.

Card number 16 was drawn 10005698 times.

Card number 17 was drawn 10006844 times.

Card number 18 was drawn 10001617 times.

Card number 19 was drawn 10001233 times.

Card number 20 was drawn 9999269 times.

Card number 21 was drawn 10005547 times.

Card number 22 was drawn 9994631 times.

Card number 23 was drawn 10006450 times.

Card number 24 was drawn 10001226 times.

Card number 25 was drawn 9997165 times.

Card number 26 was drawn 10000925 times.

Card number 27 was drawn 9999416 times.

Card number 28 was drawn 10001635 times.

P value for 27 cards=0.614170487404118

P value for 26 cards=0.880271821699275

P value for 25 cards=0.923499170502961

P value for 24 cards=0.624287793606294

P value for 23 cards=0.463782431271392

P value for 22 cards=0.0918275795728352

P value for 21 cards=0.848413464526898

P value for 20 cards=0.437303155192944

P value for 19 cards=0.605302075922096

P value for 18 cards=0.0293628427079152

Card number 1 was drawn 9999153 times.

Card number 2 was drawn 10004923 times.

Card number 3 was drawn 9993127 times.

Card number 4 was drawn 10001637 times.

Card number 5 was drawn 10000355 times.

Card number 6 was drawn 9999963 times.

Card number 7 was drawn 10002201 times.

Card number 8 was drawn 9999522 times.

Card number 9 was drawn 9997863 times.

Card number 10 was drawn 10004625 times.

Card number 11 was drawn 10001398 times.

Card number 12 was drawn 10005456 times.

Card number 13 was drawn 10001133 times.

Card number 14 was drawn 9997193 times.

Card number 15 was drawn 9992970 times.

Card number 16 was drawn 10007465 times.

Card number 17 was drawn 9996850 times.

Card number 18 was drawn 9994166 times.

P value for 17 cards=0.463159193420478

P value for 16 cards=0.901074254855155

P value for 15 cards=0.623196060523292

P value for 14 cards=0.16131153037034

P value for 13 cards=0.39322339086841

P value for 12 cards=0.239425750163672

P value for 11 cards=0.465057310698378

P value for 10 cards=0.147910602845352

P value for 9 cards=0.223291445001854

P value for 8 cards=0.567005883891805

P value for 7 cards=0.660822108546329

P value for 6 cards=0.465832956027658

P value for 5 cards=0.586291324248852

P value for 4 cards=0.537424479438887

P value for 3 cards=0.472376330829859

P value for 2 cards=0.767529320894893

Comment: I don't really follow your algorithm. Why not just assign numbers from 1-52 for the different cards & randomly shuffle their order. Then the 1st 13 were 'assigned' to player 1, etc?

Comment: @gung The algorithm mimicks the manual dealing of a deck of cards, more a psychological thing I guess :-) I will try it the way you suggest too.

Comment: I'm not sure how well it actually mimics manual dealing. The algorithm I suggested above (shuffle the order = shuffle the cards) mimics the dealing rather well, you'd just assign the cards to players by card 1 -> player 1, card 2 -> player 2, ..., card 5 -> player 1, etc, instead of the 1st 13 cards to player 1, which only simplifies the code slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the null hypotheses were true, 5% of the time you should get a p-value below 0.05.

You did 51 tests, so on average you should get 2.55 with p-values below 0.05.

If the tests were all independent, it would even be slightly surprising if you didn't get at least one of them below 0.05.

You got the most likely number of rejections if the RNG was actually random.

Nothing surprising is happening here.

Comment: After thinking it over, I keep having trouble to get my head around this: I thought that larger samples would make it more likely to get obtain a p value close to one every time. But you say that no matter what the sample size you always will have one in twenty with a p value of 0.05 or lower?

Comment: If you use a (true) significance level of 0.05 and *the null hypothesis is true*, yes. That's how they're constructed! (In practice, of course, null hypotheses are almost never perfectly true.)